# Pattern attribute is not working properly

Tags: html, forms, validation

I want a input box where it can only have alphabets and numbers with minimum number of letters of 4 and max of 20. To do this, I have the following code.

```
<input type="text" name="sample" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9].{4,20}" />
```

This pattern attribute is preventing me from submitting the form. When I type something more than one letter, it tells me to match the required format. 
What am I doing wrong? How can I have this form only take alphabets and numbers from 4-20 letters?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wildcard `.` in your pattern.  It is what is being matched 4 to 20 times.  Try

```
<input type="text" name="sample" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,20}" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fwt2cj3o/